# Calculating Cosine Similarity Between Two Points in Hyperspherical Coordinate

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, metric-spaces, spherical-coordinates, spheres

I'm working with points in an n-dimensional hyperspherical coordinate system, in other words, my points are in the shape $(r, \theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_{n-1})$. I want to calculate the angle between two points but I'm facing difficulties.

Given two points in an n-dimensional [hyperspherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates), how to compute their cosine similarity?

I know I can first convert them to Cartesian points and then calculate the angle between them, but isn't there a more straightforward way?